# Disk capacity does not match allocated plus unallocated space

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery

I have a 2TB HDD. I tried doing many ungodly operations on it one day (partition, extend, split, format). It was stupid. Now all my files on it are gone.

But the disk doesn't even show me the unpartitioned space so that I can run recovery software on it. Here is how it looks
[image]

As you can see, **capacity is 2TB but partitioned + unpartitioned space is about 170GB**

Here is the result of `diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk3
   1:               Windows_NTFS System Reserved         104.9 MB   disk3s1
   2:                      Linux                         524.3 MB   disk3s5
   3:               Windows_NTFS New Volume              160.5 GB   disk3s6
```

All I want is to recover my lost files from the 1200GB on unpartitioned space that isn't showing up for some reason. How do I fix this? How do I recover my files? :(

Comment: Post the result of Terminal `diskutil list` into your question.

Comment: result of `diskutil list` added to question

Comment: Try booting the latest [GParted Live](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) and doing a CHECK of the partition.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a missing partition run Testdisk.
For a fingerprinting based file searc run Photorec.

Both are available at

www.cgsecurity.org